# How to check with Win32 API if an app is installed from Windows store?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to write a C++ program to check if an app is downloaded from Microsoft Store or not. This app can be natively installed using setup.exe file, which I can detect by reading the registry path that it initializes to.

Unfortunately when it is installed from App Store the registry path is different.

Can someone suggest me any Winn32 api for this to check if an app is installed from MS Store or reliable work arounds?

Comment: I don't know if there is an API for this, but in Powershell you can check if a Store app is installed by using `Get-AppxPackage -Name "Appname"`

Comment: Microsoft have a sample showing how to enumerate packages installed on the machine: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/PackageManagerFindProvisionedPackages

Comment: @RemyLebeau Correct, a Windows Runtime type (*any* Windows Runtime type) isn't accessible via COM. Not sure why that'd be an issue. The C# sample translates to C++/WinRT code almost mechanically: Remove any `new`'s, remove all exception handling, and replace `var` with `auto`. That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 2):

Using WinRT APIs you should be able to check the `SkuStoreId` of the `StoreAppLicense` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-license-info-for-apps-and-add-ons): it should not be empty if the app is installed from the Windows Store.

Sample code using C++/WinRT:

```cpp
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Services.Store.h>

using namespace winrt::Windows::Services::Store;

StoreContext storeContext = StoreContext::GetDefault();

auto task = storeContext.GetAppLicenseAsync();
task.Completed([](auto&& task, auto&& status) {
    StoreAppLicense license = task.GetResults();
    bool isInstalledFromWindowsStore = !license.SkuStoreId().empty();
    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in MSDN, you can find out how an application is installed in your Windows wither from Windows store or not by using of FindPackagesByPackageFamily API.

This API has been documented here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/appmodel/nf-appmodel-findpackagesbypackagefamily.

This Windows system call allows you to find packages installed on the system by their package family name. However, if the app (for example, Windbg Preview) is installed from the Microsoft Store, it will have a package family name associated with it. So with this API you can check it out:

```
bool WindowsStoreInstalltionCheck(const wchar_t* arg_package_family_name)
{
    UINT32 count = 0;
    LONG result = FindPackagesByPackageFamily(arg_package_family_name, PACKAGE_FILTER_HEAD | PACKAGE_FILTER_DIRECT, &count, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

    return (result == ERROR_SUCCESS && count > 0);
}
```